# ion-spinner not showing in the center of ion-avatar

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, sass, spinner

In my Ionic3 project, I am trying to display a spinner in the center of an image.
Following are my HTML and SCSS files.

> HTML:

```
<ion-item no-lines no-padding>
  <ion-avatar item-start no-margin>
      <img [src]="imgURL" (load)="loaded = true"/>
      <ion-spinner class="imgSpinner" *ngIf="loaded"></ion-spinner>
  </ion-avatar>
<ion-label no-margin>{{name}}</ion-label>
</ion-item>
```

> SCSS:

```
  .imgSpinner{
      position: fixed;
      top: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      right: 0px;
      bottom: 0px;
      margin: auto;
      z-index: 9;
  }
```

The problem is `ion-spinner` is not considering `ion-avatar` as a parent. Instead, it is taking `ion-item` as the parent and showing in the center of it.
Please help.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Fix it this way.

Take parent of both text and image and put `position: relative` to it

Then take spinner and add this css

```css
.spinner {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
```

Position absolute witll 'clip' to first relative postioned element and positon itself 50% left of parent and then go back for 50% of itself which will center it perfectly

Read [here](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/positioning) about positioning element. You should know it perfectly. It is really important thing

Hope this help